# why is this not running, multiple errors

Tags: c++11

i have copied and pasted the solution of this leetcode problem, yet it doesn't run successful when I go to terminal and select run task. Any help is greatly appreciated[attached photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkMb5.png)

i think my problem is either #include something or maybe std::, but if i do std:: then i would have to do alot of std::

Comment: Yes the problem is the missing `std::` prefix. And yes there's going to be a lot of them. And you'll get used to it very quickly.

Comment: Please post code and errors as text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

try

> #include<bits/stdc++.h> and
> use namespace std;